# Change ?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless ripple color

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to use `?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` to create borderless ripple for a `LinearLayout`, it works fine but is not clearly visible.

How can I change the default color for `?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` to make the ripple effect visible?

I've tried applying `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark` theme to the parent layout but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Theming with AppCompat blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/theming-with-appcompat-1a292b754b35#0c47):

> `colorControlHighlight` controls the ripple coloring

So creating a `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat` that sets that value to your chosen color will allow you to change the ripple color for that view and its children.

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: colorControlHighlight how can i use this to change my button ripple effect color please tell

Comment: @MateenChaudhry - as per the blog post, you add that attribute to your theme (either the theme on your whole activity or within a `ThemeOverlay` you apply to just that one button).

Comment: It's `android:colorControlHighlight`

Comment: @William - for AppCompat, no, you specifically do not want to be using `android:colorControlHighlight` - you want the AppCompat version of it

Comment: Very strange, only `android:colorControlHighlight` work for me

Comment: Is it possible to set this to a specific View ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper - theme overlays, like the one suggested here, is exactly what you apply at a specific view level using `android:theme`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Can you please update the answer to show how it's done for a single View , including a sample style? And how do you change the color programmatically, without an XML ?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative would be to make your own selector. I know it's not the same nice solution, but it could be a solution anyway:

**res/drawable/circular_item_background_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/your_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

**res/drawable-v21/circular_item_background_selector.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/your_color">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/your_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the attribute *foreground* instead of *background* works well for me:

```
<Button
...    
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
android:textColor="@color/white"
.../>
```

Comment: This requires API 23 and above, and it will affect the image inside if you use ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

If need to change the color programmatically - do it this way:

1. In your xml set background:

```xml
<View
    android:id="@+id/click_view"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" <!-- Set ripple this way -->
    android:contentDescription="@null" />
```

2. And in your code change color of it:

```kotlin
// Take borderless ripple
val ripple = clickView.background as? RippleDrawable 

// Change color here
ripple?.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED))
```

Don't know how it works for api lower 23.