# Changing the color of a checkbox shadow

Tags: android

Im currently trying to change the color of a checkbox shadow. However nothing seems to work.
I will just provide two images so you know what I mean.

[image: Normal behaviour]
[image: Unwanted behaviour]

I didn't click the checkbox, but I holded it. I didn't release "the click". When I do this when the checkbox isnt checked everythings fine, but once its checked the shadows color changes to a different color. I want that color to be the same as the first one.

I tried changing various attributes:

```
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sobald wie möglich"
        android:buttonTint="@android:color/black"
        android:foregroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:checked="true" />
```

Nothing happens. I suppose that it might not be the shadow from the checkbox, since it looks pretty much the same when clicking any other view. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/41496624/7666442

Comment: no, but sadly didnt help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious: I ended up applying a style to the checkbox that overrides the  `colorAccent` attribute to `@android:color/black`.

```
<style name="AppTheme.CheckBoxTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

Then add this to the checkbox:

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CheckBoxTheme"`